# How to link against to specific packageid in Conan

Tags: conan

I have a package with 2 binaries. The binaries only differ by a single option.

The package is a library. How can now link this package to a specific package that I require?

Answer (score 1):

There are few options:

You can use [cmake_paths](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/build_system/cmake/cmake_paths_generator.html) and discover the library name:

First, you add a `conanfile.txt`, declaring package name and `cmake_paths` generator

```
[requires]
my_package/0.1.0@user/channel

[generators]
cmake_paths
```

Second, you search the desired library from the package, by its name in your cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(myapp)

find_library(MY_LIBRARY foo REQUIRED) # the library name foo in this example
add_executable(myapp app.cpp)
target_link_libraries (myapp ${MY_LIBRARY})
```

And finally, you pass the cmake_paths to cmake, so it will find your library

```
mkdir build && cd build
conan install ..
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_paths.cmake
cmake --build .
./myapp
```

It works, but it's a bit fragile, as the consumer need to now the library name and there is no warning from CMake when the library is found, you have to add a condition to check it.

The second possible option is using [Components](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/package_information.html#package-information-components) feature, but requires a recipe modification, you can provide a different target for each library:

First, you need to update your conanfile.py, adding the components:

```py
from conans import ConanFile, CMake


class MyPackage(ConanFile):
    name = "my_package"
    version = "0.1.0"
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    options = {"shared": [True, False]}
    default_options = {"shared": False}
    generators = "cmake"
    exports_sources = "src/*"

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure(source_folder="src")
        cmake.build()

    def package(self):
        self.copy("*.h", dst="include", src="src")
        self.copy("*.lib", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.dll", dst="bin", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.dylib*", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.so", dst="lib", keep_path=False)
        self.copy("*.a", dst="lib", keep_path=False)

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.names["cmake_find_package"] = "MyPackage"
        self.cpp_info.names["cmake_find_package_multi"] = "MyPackage"
        self.cpp_info.components["libfoo"].names["cmake_find_package"] = "foo"
        self.cpp_info.components["libfoo"].names["cmake_find_package_multi"] = "foo"
        self.cpp_info.components["libfoo"].libs = ["foo"]

        self.cpp_info.components["libbar"].names["cmake_find_package"] = "bar"
        self.cpp_info.components["libbar"].names["cmake_find_package_multi"] = "bar"
        self.cpp_info.components["libbar"].libs = ["bar"]
```

As you can see, the recipe builds a package with 2 libraries, `foo` and `bar`, and use different components for each one. As CamelCase is preferred for CMake targets, the name `MyPackage` will be used for the file name and target namespace. The result will be `MyPackage::foo` and `MyPackage::bar`.

As consumer, you have to update your project too:

Now we will use [cmake_find_package](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/build_system/cmake/cmake_find_package_generator.html) generator, to avoid `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` in the command line:

```
[requires]
my_package/0.1.0@user/channel

[generators]
cmake_find_package
```

The CMake file now requires the package name, but it's checked by CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(myapp)

find_package(MyPackage REQUIRED)
add_executable(myapp app.cpp)
target_link_libraries (myapp MyPackage::foo) # We only need libfoo here
```

And finally, but simpler now, the command line:

```
mkdir build && cd build
conan install ..
cmake ..
cmake --build .
./myapp
```

Conan will generate `FindMyPackage.cmake` in `build/` which will be loaded by your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Both demonstrations achieve what you asked, but I prefer the second, because is safer, as you can create a specific target, and avoid any mistake from the customer side.

NOTE: The feature Components requires Conan >=1.27.